Empty assertion error when trying to fit DQN model in TensorFlow
I'm trying to get an RL TensorFlow model to train.
The model takes a tuple of shape (2,2) as input, and is expected to make a discrete number output.
I have updated to keras-rl2, so that is not the root of the problem.
The model is as follows:
def build_model(actions):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(layers.Input(shape=(2,2)))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())

    model.add(layers.Dense(24, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(24, activation="relu"))

    model.add(layers.Dense(actions, activation="linear"))
    return model

The model compiles flawlessly.
To train the agent, I use the following:
import os
os.environ['TF_USE_LEGACY_KERAS'] = '1'

from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(
        model=model, 
        memory=memory, 
        policy=policy, 
        nb_actions=actions,
        nb_steps_warmup=10, 
        target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])

This doesn't return any errors either.
The error comes, however, when I try to fit the model with
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=2)

It returns this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[52], line 1
----> 1 dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=2)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rl/core.py:135, in Agent.fit(self, env, nb_steps, action_repetition, callbacks, verbose, visualize, nb_max_start_steps, start_step_policy, log_interval, nb_max_episode_steps)
    133 if self.processor is not None:
    134     observation = self.processor.process_observation(observation)
--> 135 assert observation is not None
    137 # Perform random starts at beginning of episode and do not record them into the experience.
    138 # This slightly changes the start position between games.
    139 nb_random_start_steps = 0 if nb_max_start_steps == 0 else np.random.randint(nb_max_start_steps)

AssertionError: 

Yes, the assertion really is empty.
I have tried to update the packages I use, as that has been a problem before, but it seems that it doesn't solve this particular problem. I also do not think this is a problem with the environment, as only the tuple is being passed, and there have not been any problems with the environment before.

The assertion is not empty, it is right there in the code, the observation is None, means there is a problem in your environment, the observation should not be set to None.
